# What relationship does Colorado have with Inga in Mackennas gold?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mackennas-gold

In [Mackenna's gold](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064615/fullcredits/), there's a scene where Mackenna is held captive by Colorado and where Mackenna meets Hesh-Ke again after a long time.

At the start of the scene, we see Colorado dragging Inga out of a room and throwing her on the ground. Nothing else is indicated and Inga seems emotionally fine afterward.

This made me wonder...Is there anything in the movie that indicates that Colorado and Inga were in relationship prior to that scene? Did he rape her? If yes, then why is she shown as emotionally stable after the incident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did he rape her?

That's certainly the *implication*...certainly abused in some way.

> If yes, then why is she shown as emotionally stable after the incident?

**I completely disagree**...she's **clearly** traumatised after she's thrown to the ground, staring off into space and not saying anything and is pretty unresponsive.

[image]

This continues in the "cell" that she and Mackenna are put overnight until she starts to respond to his care.

Eventually she starts to act more normally but by that time she is also under the influence of "gold fever".

> Is there anything in the movie that indicates that Colorado and Inga were in relationship prior to that scene?

None whatsoever.

In fact, it's pretty clear that had never met since she is the daughter of the judge who put a price on Colorado's head...**and he doesn't know that**.

Colorado also states that he'd never met the judge.

> **Colorado:** You know it's funny. I never lay eyes on Judge Bergerman.

In fact, Colorado's men had killed the judge when he kidnapped Inga and thought that she was his wife.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation: Colardo tried to seduce Inga but she resisted successfully, he did not try to rape her, which is why her clothes are intact and there are no visible scars on her face/body. She was upset because her father was killed and she was held captive with no hope of recovery. Also note that Colarado stopped the Indian who tried to rape her in the very next scene, which indicates that he was a villain but has some morals.